# Absolute position of leaves in NLTK tree

Tags: python, tree, nlp, nltk, chunking

I am trying to find the span (start index, end index) of a noun phrase in a given sentence. The following is the code for extracting noun phrases

```
sent=nltk.word_tokenize(a)
sent_pos=nltk.pos_tag(sent)
grammar = r"""
    NBAR:
        {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns

    NP:
        {<NBAR>}
        {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}  # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
    VP:
        {<VBD><PP>?}
        {<VBZ><PP>?}
        {<VB><PP>?}
        {<VBN><PP>?}
        {<VBG><PP>?}
        {<VBP><PP>?}
"""

cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(sent_pos)
nounPhrases = []
for subtree in result.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'NP'):
  np = ''
  for x in subtree.leaves():
    np = np + ' ' + x[0]
  nounPhrases.append(np.strip())
```

For *a = "The American Civil War, also known as the War between the States or simply the Civil War, was a civil war fought from 1861 to 1865 in the United States after several Southern slave states declared their secession and formed the Confederate States of America.*", the noun phrases extracted are

*['American Civil War', 'War', 'States', 'Civil War', 'civil war fought', 'United States', 'several Southern', 'states', 'secession', 'Confederate States', 'America'].*

Now I need to find the span (start position and end position of the phrase) of noun phrases. For example, the span of above noun phrases will be

*[(1,3), (9,9), (12, 12), (16, 17), (21, 23), ....]*.

I'm fairly new to NLTK and I've looked into http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html. I tried to use *Tree.treepositions()* but I couldn't manage to extract absolute positions using these indices. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any implicit function that returns the offsets of strings/tokens as highlighted by https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1214

But you can use an ngram searcher that is used by the [RIBES score](http://www.kecl.ntt.co.jp/icl/lirg/ribes/) from https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/ribes_score.py#L123

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.translate.ribes_score import position_of_ngram
>>> s = word_tokenize("The American Civil War, also known as the War between the States or simply the Civil War, was a civil war fought from 1861 to 1865 in the United States after several Southern slave states declared their secession and formed the Confederate States of America.")
>>> position_of_ngram(tuple('American Civil War'.split()), s)
1
>>> position_of_ngram(tuple('Confederate States of America'.split()), s)
43
```

(It returns the starting position of the query ngram)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but in the case of the NP *'War'*, as there are multiple occurrences of the same word in the sentence, `position_of_ngram(tuple('War'.split()), s)` will return the index of the first occurrence which is 3 whereas the NP extracted is at index 9. Is there a work around for this? Thanks again!

Comment: @Corleone, since there's no notion of "offset", the best you can do is to either get the first instance of an ngram or recursive get the "next" instance.

Comment: @alvas, Thanks! I think I'll do that. I tried to accept the answer but my karma isn't good enough as of now :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that augments the tokens with their absolute positions in a tree string. The absolute positions can now be extracted from the leaves of any subtree.

```py
def add_indices_to_terminals(treestring):
    tree = ParentedTree.fromstring(treestring)
    for idx, _ in enumerate(tree.leaves()):
        tree_location = tree.leaf_treeposition(idx)
        non_terminal = tree[tree_location[:-1]]
        non_terminal[0] = non_terminal[0] + "_" + str(idx)
    return str(tree)
```

Example use case

```py
>>> treestring = (S (NP (NNP John)) (VP (V runs)))
>>> add_indices_to_terminals(treestring)
(S (NP (NNP John_0)) (VP (V runs_1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved token offsets of a constituent parsed tree with below code:

```
def get_tok_idx_of_tree(t, mapping_label_2_tok_idx, count_label, i):
    if isinstance(t, str):
        pass
    else:
        if count_label[0] == 0:
            idx_start = 0
        elif i == 0:
            idx_start = mapping_label_2_tok_idx[list(mapping_label_2_tok_idx.keys())[-1]][0]
        else:
            idx_start = mapping_label_2_tok_idx[list(mapping_label_2_tok_idx.keys())[-1]][1] + 1

        idx_end = idx_start + len(t.leaves()) - 1
        mapping_label_2_tok_idx[t.label() + "_" + str(count_label[0])] = (idx_start, idx_end)
        count_label[0] += 1

        for i, child in enumerate(t):
            get_tok_idx_of_tree(child, mapping_label_2_tok_idx, count_label, i)
```

Below is a constituent tree:

[image]

Outpur of above code:

```
{'ROOT_0': (0, 3), 'S_1': (0, 3), 'VP_2': (0, 2), 'VB_3': (0, 0), 'NP_4': (1, 2), 'DT_5': (1, 1), 'NN_6': (2, 2), '._7': (3, 3)}
```